# data-toggle and data-target not working as desired

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently working on an html page where I am facing the following problem.

**My problem:**

My html page allows an user to choose a subscription plan out of the following options:

1. Free
2. Standard
3. Premium

As per the user requirement, I would like to enable a file upload option only for the **Standard and Premium plan** . By using a combination of data-target and data-toggle, I have tried displaying the file upload option for both the the plans.But the file upload option works **only for the standard plan**.

**My research:**

I have gone through the following duplicate questions on Stack Overflow:

[Data-toggle and Data-target are not working as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239736/data-toggle-and-data-target-are-not-working-as-desired)

[Data-toggle and data-target are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900019/data-toggle-and-data-target-are-not-working)

[data-toggle and data-target not working in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721744/data-toggle-and-data-target-not-working-in-bootstrap)

I have also gone through the following sites :

https://www.codeschool.com/discuss/t/bootstrap-behaviour-added-via-data-toggle-not-working/11339

http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

However , I haven't found a solution to my problem :

Any help will be appreciated .

**My code : Partial**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12 row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label name ="lblfree" class="full_width"><input value="" type="radio" name="plan"> Free ( 15 Days Trial)</label>
    <label name= "lblstandard" data-toggle= "collapse" data-target= "#demo" class="full_width"><input value="" type="radio" name="plan"> Standard</label>
    <label name= "lblpremium" data-toggle= "collapse" data-target= "#demo" class="full_width"><input value="" type="radio" name="plan"> Premium</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">  
    <div id="demo" class="collapse-in">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Upload Banner </label><br>
      <input name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload-id" onchange="ZFLive.addFileUploadFields('FileUpload')" type="file">
      <i>(21.For Standard Plan Banner Resolution is n*n 2.For Premium Plan Banner Resolution is n*n)</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that bootstrap allow you only yo **toggle**. If you want a bit more complex behavior, you should write it by yourself (If you need help let me know by [mention](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) me in a comment)

Comment: mosh ..thanks for extending your help , how can I proceed in this case? can i write javascript code for this ?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, I think that you need to write some code.

So the logic is to check which checkbox is `:checked`, get the value and check if you need to `slideUp` or `slideDown`.

```js
var checkboxes = $('[name="plan"]').change(function() {
  var val = checkboxes.filter(':checked').val();
  var demo = $('#demo');
  if (val != 'free') {
    demo.slideDown();
  }
  else {
    demo.slideUp();  
  }
});
```

```css
#demo {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12 row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label name ="lblfree" class="full_width"><input value="free" type="radio" name="plan"> Free ( 15 Days Trial)</label>
    <label name= "lblstandard" class="full_width"><input value="stardant" type="radio" name="plan"> Standard</label>
    <label name= "lblpremium" class="full_width"><input value="premium" type="radio" name="plan"> Premium</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">  
    <div id="demo">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Upload Banner </label><br>
      <input name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload-id" onchange="ZFLive.addFileUploadFields('FileUpload')" type="file">
      <i>(21.For Standard Plan Banner Resolution is n*n 2.For Premium Plan Banner Resolution is n*n)</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```